# Show/Hide Function with Multiple Div IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

So I know close to nothing about jQuery - but I swear I'm trying to learn. The thing is, I've got some code that works - but I know it's repetitive and probably not kosher for a real programmer - which is why I've turned to you all.

So what I want to do is show/hide (or toggle - whatever you think is best) some informational divs, or so you might call them, on this page: [Click for some pretty darn bad jQuery coding](http://vefmomentum.com/events/)

Anyway, the show/hide code that I have right now stands at this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#meet_growlab, #buddy_tv').hide();

    $('a#growlab').click(function(){
    $('#meet_growlab').show('slow');
});

    $('a#growlab_close').click(function(){
    $('#meet_growlab').hide('slow');
})

    $('a#buddytv').click(function(){
    $('#buddy_tv').show('slow');
});

    $('a#buddytv_close').click(function(){
    $('#buddy_tv').hide('slow');
})


});
```

With the HTML being (well the gist of it being...):

```
<div id="meet_growlab">BLAH BLAH BLAH
<p><a href="#" id="growlab_close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<div id="buddy_tv">BLAH BLAH BLAH
<p><a href="#" id="buddytv_close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="growlab" rel="#meet_growlab">Meet GrowLab - Canada’s Y-Combinator Arrives in Vancouver (June 24, 2011)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="buddytv" rel="#buddy_tv">Building the Web's Best Entertainment-Based Community Site: Andy Liu, CEO and Founder of BuddyTV (April 1, 2011)</a></li>
</ul>
```

So yeah - it works, but it's not pretty. And I know you guys can help me make it pretty, so...will you?

Comment: This should probably go to the [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: With this HTML the code is fine imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it so that your content slides up and down using the slideToggle function, as well as using the "close" button provided. This is what it would look like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="meet_growlab" class="content">BLAH BLAH BLAH
    <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<div id="buddy_tv" class="content">BLAH BLAH BLAH
    <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="open" rel="#meet_growlab">
        Meet GrowLab - Canada’s Y-Combinator Arrives in Vancouver (June 24, 2011)
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="open" rel="#buddy_tv">
        Building the Web's Best Entertainment-Based Community Site: Andy Liu, CEO and Founder of BuddyTV (April 1, 2011)
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.content').hide();

$('.open').click(function(){
    var section = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(section).slideToggle();
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.content').slideUp();
});
```

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pXh37/

This way, you can add additional sections of content later without changing any of the jQuery code. There's a pretty good post about it here:

http://www.ben-holland.co.uk/blog/coding/keeping-things-simple-and-generic-in-jquery/

Comment: I like this even better! Thanks hollandben!

Comment: Just for the hell of it, because I've always wanted to know, hollandben is there a way to write this so that there can only be one "hidden" div appearing at a time?

Comment: yeh sure. all you have to do is tell jQuery to close all .content containers before it opens another. i've altered it here, hope it helps... http://jsfiddle.net/hollandben/pXh37/3/

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! I'm slowly but surely learning the basics of jQuery - so to you all, thanks!

Comment: everything will click soon enough. hit me up on twitter @hollandben or check out my blog. theres some jQuery tutorials on there

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is this annoying behavior where the viewport is changed when the link is clicked. You can use "return false;" to fix this; e.g.

```
$('a#buddytv_close').click(function() {
    // Do whatever.

    return false;
}
```

I THINK what you is to toggle between showing/hiding. It's not really necessary for all that markup, [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) can go it nicely for you; e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/wzdTL/. In the "Output" window -- the bottom right -- you can click to toggle between showing and hiding the content.

The "return false" for the JS bit is to stop event propagation, because the hyperlink is not really a hyperlink per se -- hence the jarring viewport change, at least in Firefox/7.0.1 -- but just to call toggle(), so we can just return false.

Comment: Hey Wayne - thanks for the answer! What annoying behaviour was it giving you? I wasn't doing anything weird when I was viewing and testing it in Chrome, but I want to make sure it isn't wonky in any browsers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **rel** attribute as link to the div. Close functionality can be write easier, see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/Ra4Ad/

**JS**

```
$('#growlab, #buddytv').click(function() {
    var obj = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(obj).show('slow');
    return false
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div').hide('slow')
    return false
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="meet_growlab">
    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<div id="buddy_tv">
    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="growlab" rel="#meet_growlab">
            Meet GrowLab - Canada’s Y-Combinator Arrives in Vancouver 
            (June 24, 2011)
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="buddytv" rel="#buddy_tv">
            Building the Web's Best Entertainment-Based Community Site: 
            Andy Liu, CEO and Founder of BuddyTV (April 1, 2011)
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So everything worked great, except the close function, which didn't just close the hidden div, but cleared the entire page! Any thoughts as to how to fix this?

Comment: probably you have other divs with class "close"? you can adjust it with class renaming

Comment: Nope - maybe it has to do with the $(this) selector targeting the parent divs?

Comment: if you can, just update this jsfiddle with your code to show what works incorrectly?

Comment: I would - but it would essentially be my entire page's CSS and HTML. The link is here, if you want to see what's happening: http://vefmomentum.com/events/

Comment: Fixed it! Used the "closest" selector instead of "parents"!